# Building catkin_ws on one computer and copying it to another

Tags: ros, cross-compiling, catkin-ws

I am trying to build my catkin_ws locally on my laptop as it has good compute, and copy it to orangepi, I am copying only devel and build to to catkin_ws on orangepi. But I am still getting error when trying to launch one launch file

```
Resource not found: arm_bringup
ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/noetic/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/src
ROS path [2]=/opt/ros/noetic/share
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi did you source the workspace?

Try

```
source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash
```

Then try to launch again.

It it does not work then check if:

- ROS version matches the laptop version
- If packages dependencies are installed
- If the arm_bringup is indeed inside your workspace "src" folder
- Check if package was compiled in your workspace

  rospack list | grep arm_bringup

Hope it works.

Comment: I already did it but it's asking for few passages also, I thought by catkin_make the workspace the packages binary will be copies to build or devel that I can use directly